# Error: no stat called StatHline

Tags: r, error-handling, ggplot2

I have a data frame as follows:

```
variable=c("D","D","C","C","C","A","B","B","B","B")
value=c(80,100,70,68,65,45,33,31,36,32)
Count=as.integer(c(5,10,4,5,2,7,3,5,6,2))
mean=c(93.3,93.3,68.2,68.2,68.2,45,33.4,33.4,33.4,33.4)
sumVarVal=data.frame(variable=variable,value=value,Count=Count,mean=mean)
```

I can make a nice plot (where the size of the square corresponds to the count of observations with that particular x-value and y-value), as shown below:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(sumVarVal, aes(variable, value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = Count), pch=15) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New")) + 
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray90", 
        size=.5, 
        colour = "black"), 
        legend.text=element_text(size=rel(1.3)), 
        legend.title=element_text(size=rel(1.3), face="plain"), 
        legend.position="bottom", 
        axis.text = element_text(size=rel(1.3)), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.3))) + 
  labs(x="Learning Outcome", y = "Percentage Grade")
```

However, I used to have an additional piece of code (at the end of the syntax) that allowed me to superimpose a horizontal bar on each of the four topics, indicating the mean percentage grade. Those values are stored in df$mean. Here is the code I was using:

```
ggplot(sumVarVal, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Count), pch=15) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New")) + 
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray90", size=.5, colour = "black"), 
        legend.text=element_text(size=rel(1.3)), 
        legend.title=element_text(size=rel(1.3), face="plain"), 
        legend.position="bottom", 
        axis.text = element_text(size=rel(1.3)),
        axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.3))) + 
  labs(x="Learning Outcome", y = "Percentage Grade") + 
  geom_errorbar(stat = "hline", width=0.6, colour = "blue", size = 1, aes(ymax=..y..,ymin=..y.., yintercept = mean))
```

With version `1.0.1`, this gives:

[image]

With version `2.0.0`, it now leads to an error:

> Error: no stat called StatHline.

I know this may be connected to recent upgrades in ggplot2. I have seen other recent comments about it ([geom_errorbar - "No stat called StatHline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734218/geom-errorbar-no-stat-called-stathline)). However, due to my code surrounding the use of `stat="hline"`, when I tried some of these suggestions, I was not able to get my code to work either. Perhaps there is something I do not understand about my original code that is preventing me from being able to update this issue?

EDIT: I have taken into account some of the suggestions, and am currently using this code:

```
ggplot(sumVarVal, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Count), pch=15) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New")) + 
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray90", size=.5, colour = "black"), 
        legend.text=element_text(size=rel(1.3)), 
        legend.title=element_text(size=rel(1.3), face="plain"), 
        legend.position="bottom", 
        axis.text = element_text(size=rel(1.3)),
        axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.3))) + 
  labs(x="Learning Outcome", y = "Percentage Grade") + 
  geom_errorbar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", width=0.6, colour = "blue", size = 1, aes(ymax=..y..,ymin=..y.., yintercept = mean))
```

This gives me an output that looks like this:

[image: My current output]

It seems that some of the mean blue lines are not lining up to their values, as given originally in the mean vector. For instance, for variable "D", it should have a mean value of 93.3, but the blue horizontal line seems to be displayed at a value of 90.0. The effect is even more dramatic in my real code (not this MWE). Any ideas what might be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: There is no object `sumVarVal`. Please test your example before posting it.

Comment: `stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean"` seems to work.

Comment: Thank you @alistaire! Sorry @Pascal; I need to remember to remove all my variables before creating and testing my MWE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [geom\_errorbar - "No stat called StatHline"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734218/geom-errorbar-no-stat-called-stathline)

Comment: @alistaire: I have taken into account the suggestions and links, but am noticing some discrepancies with the fun.y="mean" use. I added an EDIT to my original post to explain the kink here. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to take the mean of the `mean` variable, you'll need to use `y = mean` instead of anything with `yintercept`...

Comment: Oh! I see the problem: you've named a variable named `mean`, which is very confusing, and I misunderstood what you were trying to plot. Change `yintercept` (which I don't think exists anymore?) to just `y`, and the issue goes away.

Comment: @alistaire you should put your comment as an answer; helpful solution!

Answer (score 1):

`stat_hline` [got removed in ggplot2 2.0.0](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/releases/tag/v2.0.0), but never fear; it wasn't really necessary anyway. If you remove the `stat` argument entirely, it will default to `identity`, which is fine. (`summary` can work, too, if you prefer.) You need to change the `aes` mapping, though, changing `yintercept` to `y` to account for the new `stat`.

All together,

```
ggplot(sumVarVal, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Count), pch=15) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New")) + 
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray90", size=.5, colour = "black"), 
        legend.text=element_text(size=rel(1.3)), 
        legend.title=element_text(size=rel(1.3), face="plain"), 
        legend.position="bottom", 
        axis.text = element_text(size=rel(1.3)),
        axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.3))) + 
  labs(x="Learning Outcome", y = "Percentage Grade") + 
  geom_errorbar(width=0.6, colour = "blue", size = 1, aes(ymax=..y.., ymin=..y.., y = mean))
```

produces

[image: plot with mean bars in right place]